# has_one with many to many table architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to have a has_one relation between tables connected through a many-to-many table? By default it raises an exception on a missing foreign_key in the child table.

Just as an example:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roads_travelled, class_name: 'Road'
  has_one :last_road_travelled, {order{travelled_at.desc}.limit(1)}, class_name: 'Road'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use an instance method instead of the relation:

```
def last_road_travelled
  roads_travelled.order(travelled_at: :desc).first
end
```